# Game Center - Sending Match Data and Player 1's result with turn

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, game-center, gamekit

Im developing a game center based 2 player game. The game play is;

1) Player 1 initiates the challenge.
2) Player 1 takes his/her turn. (Answers 5 questions asked by the game)
3) Player 1 sends 5 questions stored in an array plus his/her score info.
4) Player 2 receives the challenge and accepts it.
5) Player 2 answers the same questions and display the results of both players.
6) Player 1 is notified about player 2's result.
7) The match is set ended.

Im using the following code;

```
- (IBAction)sendTurn:(id)sender {
GKTurnBasedMatch *currentMatch = [[GCTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedInstance] currentMatch];


NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:challengedQuestions]; //sends same same questions answered by player1 to player 2 in an array


NSUInteger currentIndex = [currentMatch.participants indexOfObject:currentMatch.currentParticipant];
GKTurnBasedParticipant *nextParticipant;

NSUInteger nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % [currentMatch.participants count];
nextParticipant = [currentMatch.participants objectAtIndex:nextIndex];

for (int i = 0; i < [currentMatch.participants count]; i++) {
    nextParticipant = [currentMatch.participants objectAtIndex:((currentIndex + 1 + i) % [currentMatch.participants count ])];
    if (nextParticipant.matchOutcome != GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit) {
        NSLog(@"isnt' quit %@", nextParticipant);
        break;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"nex part %@", nextParticipant);
    }
}

if (turnCounter > 0)
{
    for (GKTurnBasedParticipant *part in currentMatch.participants) {
        part.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeTied;
    }
    [currentMatch endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:data completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    }];
    statusLabel.text = @"Game has ended";
    LYResultsViewController *controller = [[LYResultsViewController alloc] init];
    [controller setChallenge:self.challenge];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
else {

    [currentMatch endTurnWithNextParticipant:nextParticipant matchData:data completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
            statusLabel.text = @"Oops, there was a problem.  Try that again.";
        }
        else {
            statusLabel.text = @"Your turn is over.";
            LYResultsViewController *controller = [[LYResultsViewController alloc] init];
            [controller setChallenge:self.challenge];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
        }
    }];
}
NSLog(@"Send Turn, %@, %@", data, nextParticipant);
turnCounter++;
```

}

**The problem is that how can I send both the array and player 1's score into the same NSData variable?**

**How can I notify Player 1 about Player 2's Result?**

Please help

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add your challenge questions and the players scores to a dictionary. Just remember to use nscoding compliant objects in your dictionary and to use a placeholder dictionary to copy to from your match data. Took me forever to realize I had to copy the match data to a different dictionary to access it. As far as score results, you will just assign the score you transferred to a label and display it. If you are talking about a push notification I suggest you read http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1 for info on basic notifications. Game center handles most of it nicely though.

Here is a snippet of one of my turn actions to send match data for visual guidance:

```
- (IBAction)sendRequirement:(id)sender
{
_submitReq.enabled = NO; //Button that was pressed

_playersTurn.text = @"Submitting turn...";

GKTurnBasedMatch *currentMatch = [[GCTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedInstance] currentMatch];

NSMutableDictionary *tempLoad = [_turnData mutableCopy]; //NSMutableDictionary that holds a copy of the match data

if ([[tempLoad objectForKey:@"p2Name" ] isEqualToString:@"Player 2"])
    {
    [tempLoad setObject:[_turnData objectForKey:@"p2Name"] forKey:@"p2Name"];
    }

[tempLoad setObject:[tempLoad objectForKey:@"p1Score"] forKey:@"p1Score"];
[tempLoad setObject:[tempLoad objectForKey:@"p2Score"] forKey:@"p2Score"];
[tempLoad setObject:[_turnData objectForKey:@"choice"] forKey:@"choice"];
[tempLoad setObject:_textView.text forKey:@"req"];
[tempLoad setObject:@"Win or Lose" forKey:@"outcome"];
[tempLoad setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"turn1"];
[tempLoad setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"turn2"];
[tempLoad setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"turn3"];
[tempLoad setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"turn4"];

NSData *testData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:tempLoad
                                                              format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0
                                                             options:0
                                                               error:NULL];

NSUInteger currentIndex = [currentMatch.participants indexOfObject:currentMatch.currentParticipant];

NSMutableArray *nextParticipants = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [currentMatch.participants count]; i++)
    {
    NSInteger indx = (i + currentIndex + 1) % [currentMatch.participants count];
    GKTurnBasedParticipant *participant = [currentMatch.participants objectAtIndex:indx];

    if (participant.matchOutcome == GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeNone)
        {
        [nextParticipants addObject:participant];
        }
    }

[currentMatch endTurnWithNextParticipants:nextParticipants
                              turnTimeout:4320
                                matchData:testData
                        completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                            if (error)
                                {
                                NSLog(@"%@", error);

                                _choiceLabel.text = @"Oops, there was a problem. Try that again.";
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                _playersTurn.text = @"";
                                _choiceLabel.text = @"";

                                [self layoutMatch:currentMatch];

                                _submitReq.enabled = YES;
                                }
                        }];
}
```

I hope that helps a little. Sorry I didn't find this sooner. Good luck!